# Create anonymous type with mutable fields?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I can create an anonymous class easily using the below. However I can't write to it. Is there a way I can write to some sort of unnamed class?

```
var test = new { a = 5, b = "sz" };
test.a++;
```

Comment: this looks like it's been answered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043848/non-read-only-alternative-to-anonymous-types).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with anonymous types because the properties of an anonymous class are read-only. As to why, you can read here:

[Why are the properties of anonymous types in C# read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of reminding the poster that their own assertion is correct. This doesn't seem like an answer to me.

Comment: @spender "tldr; not possible", which answers the question. (Now, this entire question is a duplicate, but that's another issue ..)