# Can't edit DataGridView content (even when ReadOnly = false) when clicking on it?

Tags: c#, datagridview

The context here is I use a special kind of DataSource for DataGridView, that is an anonymous type which can be created as follow:

```
var data = new[] { new { A = "A", B = 1 }, new { A = "B", B = 2 }, new { A = "C", B = 3 }};
```

The problem is if I use the above data source for a DataGridView, I can't edit the content of the DataGridView starting by clicking on its cells.

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = data;
```

Could you please explain to me why and how to make it editable? Or simply we can't make it work that way?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I see that you are setting the DataSource but were are you actually `Binding` the DataSource... also can you show the code of where you are actually trying to edit the row.. also look at `myDataGridView.BeginEdit()` Method

Comment: No, I don't try editing its content programmatically, simply double-click on its cells (This behavior should allow user to edit the clicked cell). But as I said, it's impossible like as it's readable only (ReadOnly = true), but I'm sure the ReadOnly is false. Thanks

Comment: `Nothing is Impossible` it would help if you would post the code that you have in the `DoubleClick` Event..

Comment: You can only cast anonymous types as that of system.object, and those are read-only.

Comment: There is no code for DoubleClick event, why don't you try adding a DataGridView on a form, assign its DataSource with an anonymous type (as in my question) and run the project. That's all I do, no other code. If you mean I should add some code to DoubleClick event to work around this, I'll try, but if you try first and post your code here, I'm really appreciated for that. Thanks.

Comment: @AseemGautman has answered this now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because `var data` is [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx). And anonymous type properties are [read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only).

Comment: Just to add to this anser, check this link out :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043848/non-read-only-alternative-to-anonymous-types

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about this but I think that you can't edit the grid because you are binding  an anonymous type. Anonymous types cannot be changed.