# Is winform PropertyGrid able to edit dynamic object?

Tags: winforms, propertygrid, dynamicobject

As we know that by default the winform PropertyGrid is able to edit properties of a predefined class.  However, some times we might need to edit dynamic created objects.  Refer to the code below:

```
ParamForm.Show(new { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Herby" })
```

The ParamForm window contains 2 controls, a PropertyGrid and a Button.  It is designed to be able to edit dynamic objects which contains string or boolean fields only.

```
public static dynamic Show(dynamic args)
{
    var frm = new ParamForm(args);
    frm.ShowDialog();
    return frm.Result;
}
public ParamForm(dynamic args)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    propertyGrid.SelectedObject = ag;
}
```

The problem is that the Firstname & Lastname displayed in PropertyGrid control is grayed out and cannot be edited.  So how to make the PropertyGrid able to edit dynamic created objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types have read only property descriptors (used by the property grid) by design (see here for more on this: [Non-read only alternative to anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043848/non-read-only-alternative-to-anonymous-types)).

You can however use tricks such as the `DynamicTypeDescriptorWrapper` class demonstrated here: [Fun with C# 4.0’s dynamic](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/fun-with-c-4-0-s-dynamic) that implement the [ICustomTypeDescriptor Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx)