# Syntax error in `New SomeClass { Key .SomeProperty = SomeValue }` after C# -> VB conversion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

A co-worker of mine and I both do programming. He has made a class in C# and I am working on converting it to VB.NET. I got the full class converted except for a single line, and at this point I cannot figure it out so thought a fresh set of eyes maybe able to find my error.

**Original C# code**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
```

**Converted VB.NET code**

```vb
Using client = New HttpClient(New HttpClientHandler With {Key .AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate})
```

**Error**
*Name of field or Property being initialized in an object initialize must start with '.'.*

Error is located under the 'Key'

**Last note:** I used a dreaded code-converter for most of it, so I am unsure where 'key' came from.

Comment: And make sure you have `Option Infer On`.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you need to do this?

Comment: @NicoE We are working on a program to automate the ticketing software ServiceNow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two concepts which have similar syntax but different semantics:

**Anonymous Types**

C#: `new { A = 1, B = 2 }`

VB: `New With { Key .A = 1, Key .B = 2 }`

Here, [VB *also* allows you to add mutable (non-key) properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx), which [C# does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065678/87698):

`New With { Key .A = 1, Key .B = 2, .SomeMutableProperty = 3 }`

Hence, the `Key` keyword is important here.

**Object Initializers for Named Types**

C#: `new MyClass { A = 1, B = 2 }`

VB: `New MyClass With { .A = 1, .B = 2 }`

Here, *existing properties of MyClass* are set, so the `Key` keyword is irrelevant, and, thus, not allowed.

---

Apparently, your C# -> VB converter thought that this was an anonymous type, although it was an object initializer. Remove the `Key` keyword and send a bug report to the converter's developer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the `Key` has come from.

Running this through Instant VB gives the following, so it would concur with my thought that the `Key` is not required:

```
Option Infer On

Using client = New HttpClient(New HttpClientHandler With {.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate})
```

Comment: And thats why I needed a fresh set of eyes lol... Awesome that fixed it. I will mark as answered when the timer runs out.